# 70-667 and 70-668 towards SharePoint 2013

Tags: certification, 70-667

I have heard that if you have passed both the 70-667 and 70-668 exams pertaining to SharePoint 2010, they will be equivalent to one of the SharePoint 2013 exams. Anyone know or have any information on which SharePoint 2013 exam these 2 tests will count towards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right, I read it on MSDN a while ago that you can upgrade your certifications to SharePoint 2013 by giving some extra exams instead of going through all of them, I will try to find a link for you now.

**Update**

I just spoken to a Microsoft Adviser and they said,

If you have earned MCITP: SharePoint Administrator 2010 (667 and 668) then you only need to pass 3 exams to upgrade to MCSE SP 2013.

Those exams are **417, 331 and 332**

There isn't any upgrade path for MCPD SP 2010 came out yet.

For more information check this [link](http://sharepointbulletin.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/upgrading-your-mcitp-sharepoint.html) out.

Comment: thanks Muhammad for the info! Its nice you can skip the 410, 411, and 412!